# Can't use basic angular directives (like *ngFor and *ngIf) in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to use `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` in an Ionic app, but the page is not opening. It says that "it isn't a known property".

The app module already contains the `BrowserModule` import and the page module contains the `CommonModule`. I'm already declaring the variable in the 'page.ts' file and the variable used in the `ngFor` is an array. I also tried running `npm i and npm update`, deleting `node_modules` and installing again.

```
<ion-list lines="none">
<ion-item  *ngfor="let msg of messages">
{{ msg.text }}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Make sure to spell it correctly in code: `ngFor` (with a capital F).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct syntax with correct spelling (**upperCase F**):

```
<ion-list lines="none">
  <ion-item  *ngFor="let msg of messages">
     {{ msg.text }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```